# How to create a Circle input button with ring outside it?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have working right now. Just trying to figure out how to add another small circle inside it to get it to make exactly like the image I included above.

```css
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #0f8c73;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #0f8c73;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .checkmark:after {
    top: 3.5px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
</style>
<body>

<h1>Custom Radio Buttons</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to replicate this. I'm not sure how to implement this way using CSS. Currently, I just have a circle check box working. Not sure how to add the ring or shrink the inner circle.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a [radio button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)?  If you're making a checkbox that looks like a radio button, that will be quite confusing for the user because it will behave differently than the visuals suggest it will by convention...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexander makes a good point about whether this is better suited semantically as a radio button.

Either way the approach to add a border with a gap is to combine `border` and `box-shadow`:

```
.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: teal;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px teal;
}
```

Snippet in action below:

```css
.round {
  position: relative;
}

.round label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 28px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: teal;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px teal;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="round">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  <label for="checkbox"></label>
</div>
```